# Having trouble assigning the result of a Solve to a function

Tags: equation-solving

Can anyone see what is wrong with my syntax? It looks like I have successfully assigned the result of Solve to a function. I want *Mathematica* to return me an numeric value of the function `fc1`.

```
eq1 = (x - Subscript[c, 1])^2 + (Subscript[τ, c] + 
      Tan[Subscript[ϕ, LIN]] x)^2 == (Subscript[σ, SF] - 
      Subscript[c, 1])^2 + Subscript[τ, SF]^2;
eq2 = (x - Subscript[c, 
      1]) + (Subscript[τ, c] + 
       Tan[Subscript[ϕ, LIN]] x) Tan[Subscript[ϕ, LIN]] == 0;
sols = Solve[eq1 && eq2, {Subscript[c, 1], x}]

fc1[Subscript[τ, c] _, Subscript[ϕ, LIN] _, Subscript[σ, SF] _, Subscript[τ, SF] _] := 
  Subscript[c, 1] /. sols[[1]][[1]]

ans = fc1[50, π/6*1.1, 1000, 800]
N[ans, 3]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Probably best not to try to use subscripts in this way, but use explicit symbol names, e.g.:

```
ClearAll[eq1, eq2, fc1, sols]

eq1 = (x - c1)^2 + (tauc + Tan[philin] x)^2 == (sigmasf - c1)^2 + tausf^2;
eq2 = (x - c1) + (tauc + Tan[philin] x) Tan[philin] == 0;

sols = Solve[eq1 && eq2, {c1, x}];


fc1[tauc_, philin_, sigmasf_, tausf_] := Evaluate@(c1 /. sols[[1]][[1]])


ans = fc1[50, π/6*1.1, 1000, 800]


N[ans, 3]

(*
1454.2 -463.075 I
1454.2 -463.075 I
*)
```